# API Development detailed endpoints with more requests

Tags: node.js, express, api-design

I'm using express with node to create endpoints really easily.
I have an endpoint called `/users/:uid/upload` with a POST request.
I want it to handle a massive amount of data, however sending the request with about 3.5MB of JSON gets me a 412 error (Payload too large).

My Payload contains an array of (music) artists and its albums, so `artist/:artistid/albums/:albumid`

So I thought about alternatives:

1. Alternative: Detailed endpoints with more requests

So I would create the following endpoints:

```
POST /artists/:artistid/data
POST /artists/:artistid/albums/:albumid/
```

This would make the large payload become smaller, but then I'd have `number_of_artists * number_of_albums_per_artist` requests relatively close to each other

2. Alternative: Uploading JSON as a file

I'd need to persist my data to a file and then upload it, then parse the file and store it somewhere. I'd rather not want this option as the files would need to be updated quite often.

Is there any alternative that I'm missing and would you recommend alternative 1 with many requests?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your current situation you can just increase the size limit.

Install and require [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

`const bodyParser = require('body-parser')`

Before you declare your endpoints add this:

`app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb'}))`

---

Although I'd recommend the multiple-requests to detailed endpoints since if one fails you can retry only that specific one. The entire operation doesn't fail that way. So if you got time to invest in this, the best way would be multiple endpoints.

Comment: So in general it is not a bad practise to make such huge requests?

Comment: It's not ideal. 3.5MB is big for a single request but it's not a huge amount of data either;

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to handle such large requests other than increasing the limit (which is a nice alternative to have). So you'd recommend a higher limit over multiple requests to detailed endpoints?

Comment: No I'd recommend the multiple-requests to detailed endpoints since if one fails you can retry only that specific one. The entire operation doesn't fail that way. So if you got time to invest in this, the best way would be multiple endpoints. There are more benefits to using multiple, detailed endpoints but it's hard to expand on them in a comment (memory usage kept low for stacked requests, more "ReSTful" API etc...).

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, multiple requests sound good :) thanks